# PLSQL - Use variable array on where clause IN

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, variables

I am looking to use an array of values in the WHERE IN condition.

After research, I saw that I had to make a "CREATE TYPE", since a "TYPE" in local does not work. This solution does not suit me, I do not want to make a new TYPE in Oracle, since the database is used for an ERP/PGI I do not wish to pollute with my little need.

My request is the following:

```sql
DELETE vip_routage
 WHERE vip_tel_ext = w_array_tel(i)
   AND ((w_cp NOT IN ('14', '27', '50', '61', '76') 
   AND SUBSTR(VIP_CODE_POSTAL, 1, 2) IN ('14', '27', '50', '61', '76')) 
    OR (w_cp IN ('14', '27', '50', '61', '76') 
   AND SUBSTR(VIP_CODE_POSTAL, 1, 2) IN ('14', '27', '50', '61', '76') 
   AND TO_NUMBER(vip_dest1) < w_tri_ordre) 
    OR (w_cp NOT IN ('14', '27', '50', '61', '76') 
   AND SUBSTR(VIP_CODE_POSTAL, 1, 2) NOT IN ('14', '27', '50', '61', '76') 
   AND TO_NUMBER(vip_dest1) < w_tri_ordre));
```

It is the value "('14','27','50','61','76')" that I would like to set as a variable, but only in my program.

Do you have any ideas other than "CREATE TYPE"?

Comment: What is `w_array_tel(i)`?  That looks like `w_array_tel` is a local variable that is a collection, `i` is the index of the collection, which would imply that you're already in a loop in PL/SQL.  Is that the case?  What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't want to create your own type, use built-in one - `sys.odcivarchar2list`. For example, fetch employees who are either clerks or managers:

```
SQL> select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where job in (select *
  4                from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('CLERK', 'MANAGER'))
  5               );

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
        30       7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
        20       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
        20       7369 SMITH      CLERK            800
        10       7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        30       7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
        20       7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to declare a variable whose datatype is `sys.odcivarchar2list` (so, you're in a PL/SQL procedure), then

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_job sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('CLERK', 'MANAGER');
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_cnt
  7      from emp
  8      where job in (select * from table(l_job));
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Found ' || l_cnt || ' employees');
 11  end;
 12  /
Found 7 employees

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't understand, this solution won't help me to reduce the declaration of values through a single variable

Comment: @Merurz It will. Just wrap this variable with `with codes as (select column_value as val from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(...))` and use this CTE as a general table. But you will need to pass a list of codes as a collection (though your programming language should provide some collection wrapper to build a bind variable of such type).

Comment: How do you declare the variable "codes" with what type?

Comment: I edited the answer and posted some more code; have a look.

Answer (score 1):

replace the first with clause and str with your string variable, you can do something like this:

```
with rws as (
  select '''14'',''27'',''50'',''61'',''76''' str from dual
),
item_list as (
  select regexp_substr (
           str,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, ',' ) ) + 1
)
delete from VIP_ROUTAGE
where vip_TEL_EXT = w_array_tel(i)
AND (
 (w_cp NOT IN  (select value from item_list)) ...
```

Comment: The PLSQL makes it complicated. I'll try tomorrow. If you think of something simpler, don't hesitate

Comment: There is no pl/sql in the answer i provided.

Comment: Except that PLSQL has to go through this operation, because it does not know how to take a classical array as a parameter, unlike other SQL languages

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a string (such as `'14,27,50,61,76'`) as a bind variable and use `LIKE` to compare the delimited string:

```sql
DELETE FROM VIP_ROUTAGE
WHERE vip_TEL_EXT = w_array_tel(i)
AND (    ',' || :your_list || ',' NOT LIKE '%,' || w_cp || ',%'
    AND (  ',' || :your_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || SUBSTR(VIP_CODE_POSTAL,1,2) || '%,'
        OR to_number(vip_dest1) < w_tri_ordre))
OR  (    ',' || :your_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || w_cp || ',%'
    AND  ',' || :your_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || SUBSTR(VIP_CODE_POSTAL,1,2) || ',%'
    AND  to_number(vip_dest1) < w_tri_ordre)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=58d978c91c92e0c130e5ecfa370f0e38)*

Comment: You can't use a like for a value list comparison, in a single value

Comment: @Merurz This is not, it is comparing two strings (since you state in the question that you are not creating another collection type so you cannot have a list with multiple items; hence, you must be using a scalar instead). You can check the linked db<>fiddle where you can see that the query works.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass this list of codes as a plain text (not as a bind variable of type collection), then you may use `json_table` function to expand the list into a table and use it as a general table with a subquery inside `in` predicate:

> ```
> with function f
> /*Just to emulate bind variable*/
> return varchar2
> as begin
>   return q'('X','Y','Z')';
> end;
>
> lkp as (
>   select *
>   from json_table(
>     '[' ||
>     /*
>       Your string goes here
>       instead of invocation f()
>     */
>     f()
>     || ']',
>     '$[*]'
>     columns (
>       col varchar2(100) path '$'
>     )
>   )
> )
> select *
> from dual
> where dummy in (
>   /*Filter by list*/
>   select * from lkp
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=25697fa6bba4f811fdcb7134e36c7d16)*

If you want to pass this codes as an array (collection in Oracle), then use built-in collection type `sys.odcivarchar2list`, but you'll need to prepare a bind variable of this type at the application side depending on the programming language (for example, [here's an explanation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-pl-sql-collections) with examples from the official docs for Python).